# Find a ZIG-ZAG sequence with a greedy algorithm

Tags: greedy

An integer sequence X=x1,x2...,xn is defined ZIG-ZAG  if :

xi < xi+1 if xi is an odd number
xi > xi+1 if xi is an even number

I need a greedy algorithm to find the dimension of the maximum ZIG-ZAG subsequence inside a given sequence

EDIT: 
There's an example:
Y = (3, 4, 8, 5, 6, 2)
Output should be 5 for 3, 8, 5, 6, 2 or 4, 8, 5, 6, 2

Answer (score 0):

just run through the sequence and check for each element if the condition is sattisfied.

could you try to explain what [greedy algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) have to do with this?

edit: ok, now it makes more sense then in the original.
unfortunately i can't think of a good solution atm.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've written badly the text. Now it's correct, sorry again.

Comment: If you "can't think of a good solution", it would be better to delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this algorithm(just initialise the o(dd) and e(ven) arrays to 1):

```
for i=1 to n 
for j=i-1 down to 1 do
if a[i]>a[j]  and o[i]< e[j]+1 then o[i]=e[j]+1
else if a[i]<a[j] and e[i]<o[j]+1 then e[i]=o[j]+1
```

The answer is the maximum of the o and e arrays.